# React js form not sending thourgh email js after validation

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, state

I am attempting to send a form with email.js in a React application after validation but even if there are no errors the form does not send.

I need error messages to be set if there is missing data. If at least one of the fields is missing information, the form should be sent. Once all fields are completed, the form should send and a success message should be rendered to inform the user that the form was sent.

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "../CSS/form.css";
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

const Form = () => {
  const formRef = useRef();
  const initialValues = {
    panna_mloda: "",
    pan_mlody: "",
    numer_kontaktowy: "",
    email: "",
    data: "",
    miejsce_slubu: "",
    miejsce_wesela: "",
    goscie: "",
    budzet: "",
  };
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };

  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.panna_mloda) {
      errors.panna_mloda = "Proszę wprowadzić imię Panny młodej";
    }
    if (!values.pan_mlody) {
      errors.pan_mlody = "Proszę wprowadzić imię Pana młodego";
    }
    if (!values.numer_kontaktowy) {
      errors.numer_kontaktowy = "Proszę wprowadzić numer kontaktowy";
    }
    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = "Proszę wprowadzić adres mailowy";
    }
    if (!values.data) {
      errors.data = "Proszę wprowadzić datę ślubu";
    }
    if (!values.miejsce_slubu) {
      errors.miejsce_slubu = "Proszę wprowadzić miejsce ślubu";
    }
    if (!values.miejsce_wesela) {
      errors.miejsce_wesela = "Proszę wprowadzić miejsce wesela";
    }
    if (!values.goscie) {
      errors.goscie = "Proszę wprowadzić przewidywaną liczbę gości";
    }
    if (!values.budzet) {
      errors.budzet = "Proszę wprowadzić planowany budżet na dekorację";
    }

    return errors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    setIsSubmit(true);
    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
      emailjs
        .sendForm(
          "service_*****",
          "template_*****",
          formValues.current,
          "2aRB3MFBn*****"
        )
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
          }
        );
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(formErrors);
    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
      console.log(formValues);
    }
  }, [formErrors]);
```

How can I change the validation so that the form sends when there are no errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    setIsSubmit(true);
    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
```

Here is your problem.

```
setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
```

This sets your state. **But state does not change instantly!**

```
if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit)
```

When this line runs, your state is still an empty object! You need to wait until the next render to access updated state, but your function all runs within one render. The same is true for your `setIsSubmit(true);`, it will not actually be set as true immediately.

So validate, and pass the value within the scope of the function. Let's just remove isSubmit for now, or you can set it outside of the `handleSubmit`. Here is the whole updated handleSubmit function.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const errors = validate(formValues));
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0){

      emailjs
        .sendForm(
          "service_*****",
          "template_*****",
          formValues.current,
          "2aRB3MFBn*****"
        )
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
          }
        );
    }
  };
```

https://blog.logrocket.com/why-react-doesnt-update-state-immediately/

Comment: thank you for your response but I am not sure that I understand completely. Does the line of code which you provided need to be inluded in the handelSubmit function or should it be typed outside?

Comment: I've updated it with the whole function, you should be replacing it. Make sure to understand what is different.